# Yocto: TEMPLATECONF value points to nonexistent directory

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04, yocto

I have started to work with Yocto Project. I have trouble when I try to:

```
source oe-init-build-env
```

I have just cloned poky, and checkout and pull branch I wanted, and when I tried to do:

```
source oe-init-build-env
```

it showed me:

```
Error: TEMPLATECONF value points to nonexistent directory 'meta-yocto/conf'
```

Can you help me with that. I have successfully installed all required tools for host (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Do you want to use `TEMPLATECONF` to create a custom (build) system? If not, make sure that there is no `TEMPLATECONF` environment variable present when you do `source oe-init-build-env`. If you want to use it, make sure that this environment variable is set correctly. See [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/custom-template-configuration-directory.html#creating-a-custom-template-configuration-directory) page for a bit more info (what a coincidence, they use "Alex" name in the examples)

Comment: Yes, thank you for help skandigraun! We solved that was up to version I chose (it was probably not good for my Ubuntu 18.04 version), and yes, after that it was okay.
So I have also used outdated site, so when I cloned poky, I just went to souring oe-init-build-env, without checking out proper branch which mine Ubuntu can support properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you built the oe-init-build-env previously? If yes ,Please delete the build folder and run again oe-init-build-env from poky

Comment: Thank you, we have solved this. This was up to the version I chose (it was probably not good for my Ubuntu 18.04 version), and yes, after that it was okay. So, I have also used the outdated site, so when I cloned poky, I just went to souring oe-init-build-env, without checking out the proper branch which my Ubuntu can support properly.